# How to mock a function that returns values based on its *args input?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a function `foo` that calls another function `get_info_from_tags`.

Here's the `get_info_from_tags` implementation:

```py
def get_info_from_tags(*args):
    instance_id = get_instance_id()
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["aws", "ec2", "describe-tags", "--filters", f"Name=resource-id,Values={instance_id}"],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
    em_json = json.loads(out.decode('utf8'))
    tags = em_json['Tags']  # tags list

    results = []

    for arg in args:
        for tag in tags:
            if tag['Key'] == arg:
                results.append(tag['Value'])

    return results
```

There is a set of 10 possible args that can be passed to `get_info_from_tags`, and I need to return the correct array (I don't want to make a call to aws services, that's the point of my mock, I will manually set the values in a dictionary).

How can I mock `get_info_from_tags` so that when I call

`get_info_from_tags('key1', 'key2' ...)`

inside the foo function, I get the results I want?

I've already tried some functions of pytest but, as it seems, I didn't quite understand.

A possible solution would be to create another function:

```py
def mocked_get_info_from_tags(*args):
    values = []
    for arg in args:
        values.append(my_dictionary[arg])
    return values
```

But I don't know how to implement this override within a test environment.

Thank you.

Comment: Given your implementation of `get_info_from_db` I don't see why you need to mock that function and not `db_connector.get`. Could you explain?

Comment: It's because, for simplicity, I wrote here an abstraction of my actual function, that does something more complicated than that. But the core idea is the same.
For example, in my actual function, I call subprocess and run some commands. It would be complicated to mock just the `db_connector.get` because, before it's call, it would run the subprocess command.

Comment: You could do `return [db_connector.get(arg) for arg in args]` in real conditions and `return[mock_values(arg) for arg in args]` if a certain `MOCK` attribute of your script is set to `True`.

Comment: Ok, I get it, not writing the actual function leads to the answers I didn't expect. I will edit the question with the actual function.

Comment: @TeodoroMendes I see, but what prevents you from mocking that function then? You just need to provide the mocked version to the patch. Can you be more specific about what is the actual problem?

Comment: You say you have a function `get_info_from_db` called by another function `foo`, but then show an example of some object `foo` invoking a method named `get_info_from_db`. Please clarify this in your edit.

Comment: @chepner Edited, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @a_guest, that was the point, I was using patch in the wrong way. Blazej clarified where I should patch the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) is your friend.

You didn't specify the module names, so I put some `<placeholders>` there.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from <module_with_foo> import foo
from <module_with_mock> import mocked_get_info_from_tags

with patch('<module_with_foo>.get_info_from_tags', mocked_get_info_from_tags):
    foo()
```

This will replace `get_info_from_tags` with your mocked version of this function. The replacement is done on a module level, so everything in module `<module_with_foo>` that calls `get_info_from_tags` will now call your mock.

---

**Note about the path given to `patch`**:

`patch` replaces values of module attributes. So, if you have a module `moo` with a function `foo`, which calls `bar` from module `moo2`:

```
# moo module
from moo2 import bar

def foo():
    bar()
```

...from the point of view of `patch`, `moo.foo` calls `moo.bar`, not `moo2.bar`. That's why you have to patch the module where the function is used, not where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You could call one function from the other, and then replace when you have the db setup. That way you can still call `foo.get_info_from_db('key1', 'key2' ...)` everywhere in your code and when you add the proper database connection, all you have to change is the one main `get_info_from_db` function implementation and remove the mock

```
import db_connector

def mocked_get_info_from_db(*args):
    values = []
    for arg in args:
        values.append(my_dictionary[arg])
    return values

def get_info_from_db(*args):

    # remove this once your database is setup
    return mocked_get_info_from_db(*args)

    # values = []
    # for arg in args:
    #     values.append(db_connector.get(arg))
    # return values
```

Comment: Thanks but this code will have to be tested by other developers too. So I need to build a test environment.